# Blank gray screen instead of the login page for connection server

Tags: view, virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

I've got connection server installed on a w2008r2 with domain configured on another machine connection works fine though not able open the Connection server just gets a blank gray screen

with not login page.However when a try to login in  the View client am able to login but gets error View connection server license key is invalid.

I have the Adobe flash 11 installed

I have question is it possible to install Connection server without the vCenter server ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install Connection server without vCenter server,  [see the pre-req of install](http://pubs.vmware.com/view-52/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.view.installation.doc/GUID-68621B8E-F018-4BC4-811A-5CF76B55DB2C.html) a connection server. But without vcenter we can only unmanaged guest machine...

And if you just want to access the win2k8 server. You can just use vsphere client connect to the ESXi directly.